# Error installing BerkeleyDB Perl module on mac

Tags: macos, perl, berkeley-db

I'm having the issue reported here in a smoke test: https://www.cpantesters.org/cpan/report/7bf27c72-faf6-11e6-b513-f49332c4a644

`BerkeleyDB.xs:82:2: error: db.h is from Berkeley DB 1.x - need at least Berkeley DB 2.6.4 #error db.h is from Berkeley DB 1.x - need at least Berkeley DB 2.6.4`

So looks like the headers on mac for BerkeleyDB are out of date. Is there a way to update them?

I'm on latest version of Catalina as of today, 10.15.4.

Answer (score 3):

OK, `brew install berkeley-db` did the trick.

Comment: Consider including the version of Mac OS you're talking about?

Comment: I run into this less on macOS than Ubuntu, but being old school I'm still boggled any time the development headers aren't already there. I had the same problem with a different library on Ubuntu yesterday. I'll have it next week with something else. :)